# Copy A Header To The Clipboard HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, header, clipboard

I am looking for a way to copy the text inside of a header on my website to the users clipboard. I am a beginner at HTML and JS, so I am struggling quite a bit. This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <h2>Test<h2 id="ip">

    <button onclick="copyToClipboard()">Copy To Clipboard</button>

    <script>

      function copyToClipboard() {
        var copyText = document.getElementById("ip")
        copyText.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
      }

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This script does not copy the header and I cannot figure out why. This is the error I get: `Uncaught TypeError: copyText.select is not a function` Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212

Comment: You can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987376/9987468).

Comment: `<h2>Test<h2 id="ip">` Is invalid HTML

Answer (score 0):

Your html is invalid. It should be `<h2 id='ip'>Test</h2>`
Also I wouldn't advise to use inline onclick in the button element. Instead use the addEventListener function. [Read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).